# Specifying a stereotype with a qualifier won't work?

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld

Specifying a stereotype with a qualifier?

I can't understand why it seems illegal to include a qualifier when specifying a stereotype?

Trying to do so resulted in the following error message:

```
jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: 
WELD-001103 Cannot declare qualifiers on stereotype interface
```

If this is by design I am curious to why or am I doing anything wrong?
Tried to search this but could not find anything

cheers

Comment: Include your qualifiers and stereotype code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From how I understand the specification, the *main idea* of a qualifier is to qualify a **single** bean type in case that there are ambiguous dependencies.

In contrast to that, the *main idea* of a stereotype is to bundle individual combinations of scope / named / interceptor / alternative annotatons to be re-used on **multiple** beans.

That kind of contradicts each other - so I'm not too surprised that this is forbidden by the container - event though it's only implicitly targeted by the spec (by *not* naming qualifiers as being allowed for stereotypes).